# How i can fix error with added AppMetrica to react-native project

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I tried add "react-native-appmetrica": "^1.1.0" to my react-native project.

When i tried to AppMetrica.activateWithApiKey("key") it gives an error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'AppMetrica.activateWithApiKey')

activateWithApiKey
index.js:19:19
AppInit
App.js:91:35
<global>
app.js:44:23
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:322:6
<global>
index.ios.js:9
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:322:6
guardedLoadModule
require.js:201:45
global code
index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:212249:4
```

Comment: I catched the same problem